# Is it possible to follow or bookmark a Stack Overflow user?

Tags: feature-request

There are some incredibly smart chaps around here and I'd like to read more of their answers. Just like you can bookmark threads, is there a way to bookmark other users? If not, it'll be a very useful feature.

Here's the feature description:

User A may go to the profile page of User B and click a link that reads *Follow B* or some such. Upon doing that, user A sees user B listed on his profile page under a list named *Users I Follow*. That's all. No RSS feeds, no email notifications are required for following a user.

Is this something you'd like to do?

Comment: No. No, it is not.

Answer (score 5):

Each user has a Atom feed for their posts (questions and answers) already. Find it at the bottom right-hand corner of the user profile page.

Look for the little orang feed icon:

[image: User feed link]

For example on [Jon Skeet's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/user/22656), you'll find that icon at the bottom right and it links to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656
```

And it contains:

```xml
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
    <title type="text">User Jon Skeet - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="self" href="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656" type="application/atom+xml" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656" type="text/html" />
    <subtitle>most recent 30 from stackoverflow.com</subtitle>
    <updated>2013-01-21T12:46:55Z</updated>
    <id>https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656</id>
    <creativeCommons:license>http://www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/rdf</creativeCommons:license> 

    <entry>
        <id>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438652/-/14438804#14438804</id>
        <re:rank scheme="http://stackoverflow.com">1</re:rank>
        <title type="text">Answer by Jon Skeet for Elegant way to give a delegate properties</title>
        <author>
            <name>Jon Skeet</name>
            <uri>https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656</uri>
        </author>    
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438652/elegant-way-to-give-a-delegate-properties/14438804#14438804" />
        <published>2013-01-21T12:38:20Z</published>   
        <updated>2013-01-21T12:38:20Z</updated>
        <summary type="html">&lt;p&gt;(I&#39;d recommend &lt;em&gt;not&lt;/em&gt; using the term &quot;lambda&quot; here given that you&#39;re also using lambda expressions. It sounds like you&#39;re interested in the change, i.e. the delta.)&lt;/p&gt;
```

(etc.)

Comment: I understand that. However, the problem with an RSS feed is that it is an interruption, a distraction like email. Having something like a passive list helps me remember the intelligent posters I might be interested in reading up on without any interruption or distraction to my flow of thought. This is an immensely useful thing to have. And it is a very different feature from usability point-of-view.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: Plenty of ways to manage that with modern feed tools. This is not a social networking site however; see the duplicate question.

Comment: Nothing in my question suggests that I see this as a social networking website. In fact, the feature I am requesting has nothing to do with social networking. It is a handy tool for keeping tabs on people who you think are intelligent and you want to read more of their posts to learn more.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: The site is about providing great answers to great questions; the fact that there are some here that produce more great answers than others is a happy side-effect. But since the site is focused on the answers and questions, no features are and will be offered to follow specific people. That is seen as a social-network-type feature.

Comment: No worries. I thought I'd ask anyway. Thank you for your consideration and your time.